# How to store after submitting form data in particular user account using asp.net c#

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Once user login the account and filling the form...the form information storing to database..but how to store that data in particular logged in user account?

How to store form data in loggedin user account?

Below code is form submit button:

```
protected void submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\pragmatic\Desktop\mvcapplication\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\App_Data\custresponse.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

  //s = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChartDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  //con = new SqlConnection(s);
    con.Open();
  //date = day_DropDownList.Text.ToString() + "/" + month_DropDownList.Text.ToString() + "/" + year_DropDownList.Text.ToString();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into custresponse values('" + title_Txt.Text + "','" + description_Txt.Text + "','" + money + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "','" + money1_Txt.Text + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Label1.Text = "Information submitted successfully";
    con.Close();
    clear();

}
```

Comment: once user logged in takes his/her user_id into session and when filling the form insert his/her user_id into the form table with form details

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into custresponse values('" + title_Txt.Text + "','" + description_Txt.Text + "','" + money + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "','" + money1_Txt.Text + "')", con);   In above line how to include userid in where condition?

Comment: You have a missing curly brace at the end of your code

Comment: as you take all values take one field more which is user_id first add a field user_id into your table

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your table then add a column to the table. That column will act like a flag indicating the user identity. Now Simply pass the cookie object, if created during user login, or pass user login id as a parameter to SQL database.

Other wise append the "title_Txt" with user login id using any delimiter like pipe(||) symbol. Later while retrieving the title_Txt split the content on basis of the delimiter and get the user login id back.

Comment: I am new to asp.net..I dont know,how to pass cookie object and all.Please Provide any sample code for this process.that will be help for me.

Comment: @softwaresolution Only keeping the cookie object will not help as cookie partcipates to maintain session. I will suggest to save the login id in global variable and save that as it is unique and can easily help you ti identify the user.